# Need examples on using joomla 2.5 captcha framework in my component/module

Tags: joomla, frameworks, captcha

Im NOT wanting to use recaptcha, or install a captcha, i want to use the built-in captcha framework that came as part of joomla 2.5. And add it to my custom forms and extensions.

Comment: Joomla 2.5 comes with re-captcha plugin as default captcha the integrations can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894134/using-recaptcha-with-my-custom-form-in-joomla

Comment: That is not what i am looking for - as i said i am not wanting recaptcha, i am wanting to use the captcha framework in joomla2.5 so that i can choose between captchas installed. For example the playthrough captcha. Those examples only showed configuring the recaptcha version, unless i missed something

Comment: Make sure you are running the latest version of Joomla 2.5 (2.5.17) as Google changed the URL of the reCaptcha

Comment: Im not interested in recaptcha. I want the captcha API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add captcha to a form, simply add the captcha field:  Assuming your component is `com_something`:

```
    <field
        name="captcha"
        type="captcha"
        label="COM_SOMETHING_CAPTCHA_LABEL"
        description="COM_SOMETHING_CAPTCHA_DESC"
        validate="captcha"
        namespace="something"
    />
```

The validation will handle it transparently for you.  Look into com_contact and com_users for examples i.e. `components/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml`