# Is it possible to use the Recaptcha Joomla plugin for custom pages?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Looking at [the docs](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_use_Recaptcha_in_Joomla_2.5?), it seems that it can only be used for registration and contact pages.  I would like to add captchas to an iJoomla survey.

Comment: If you're asking about adding it to a custoom extension then you should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840015/how-to-use-joomla-recaptcha-plugin-to-my-custom-module otherwise you would have to ask the iJoomla developer to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on how the component is developed.
If it supports the "standard" joomla captcha system (the one you can manage in the Configuration page), you can use it (you can even change the captcha system).
However, if the developer didn't use it or uses his own system, you can't do anything, you have to ask to the iJoomla developer.