# How to show recaptcha in all modules?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, recaptcha

I have two modules loaded in same page and both modules need captcha. So I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287929/how-to-insert-recaptcha-into-my-custom-joomla-2-5-module) but it is only showing in only one module.

If I remove captcha from module1 and keep captcha in module2 then captcha shows in module2 but if I add captcha to module1 too then it only shows in module1 but not in module2.

So, how can I use the code so that in both modules the captcha would be shown?

I've tried by renaming

```
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');
```

To this:

```
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_2');
```

But also no success.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to rename

```
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_2"></div>
```

as well.

Although, I did not try it, I think that it is going to work.